# Import json object into SQLite

Tags: json, angularjs, sqlite

I'm new to angularjs and I'm creating an offline app. I'm trying to import some json objects inside a SQLite database.

I create the db with Angular and everything was fine. Now I must process the objects:
Every object has a structure like this:

```
{
  "id" : 5306,
  "quiz_type" : "oltre",
  "error_count" : 0,
  "done_count" : 0,
  "text" : "Su quale pubblicazione dell'Istituto Idrografico della Marina si possono ricavare informazioni più specifiche sulle maree?",
  "image" : {
    "image" : {
      "url" : "/images/fallback/default.png"
    }
  },
  "section" : {
    "name" : "Navigazione"
  },
  "answers" : [
    {
      "text" : "Sul Portolano",
      "correct" : false
    },
    {
      "text" : "Sulle Effemeridi Nautiche",
      "correct" : false
    },
    {
      "text" : "Sulle Tavole di marea",
      "correct" : true
    }
  ]
}
```

I cannot store json object inside the db because I must query for random object filtering by section, error_count and done_count.
I can add an item to my db, but I cannot understand how can I handle association.
How can I create a query that insert one object inside my db with association?

I already created the schema.